# Bluetooth adapter might render switch unusable?

Tags: nintendo-switch

‘...Unauthorized modification of the hardware or software of you Nintendo Switch system, or the use of an unauthorized device in connection with your system, may render the system permanently unusable.’

Does this include bluetooth adapters? Also, could an adapter brick my switch via power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that the Bluetooth adapters that you plug into the USB-C plug at the bottom do not modify the software of the Switch so it should not be a problem.

This thing is really about opening your switch and doing things like modifying the internal components, or modify the software that is running on the switch. The bluetooth adapters, as far as I know, do neither. They use the fact that you can output sound via the USB-C plug and then convert that sound signal to bluetooth for your bluetooth headphones.

So yeah as long as the thing you buy does not request you physically open the Switch, I do not think that the blueetooth dongles cause a problem for the Switch TOS.

Comment: What about the part where it says ‘use of an unauthorized device in connection?’ Should that be if concern? (They don’t sell official switch bluetooth adapters)

Comment: Hmmm, for that you should maybe contact nintendo what would be an unauthorized device. Because they might be (seeing as there seem to be no big audio companies doing such a dongle, it all looks like cheap knockoffs.) But really, I do not think those dongles cause such a big problem. The unauthorized device thing must be there just so they dont have to debug you if you plug stuff that is truly destructive in your switch.

Comment: By truly destructive to your switch, back in the Wii days one of my friends would homebrew Wiis (for those who wanted to do so but didn't really know how). So he had the thing that installs the homebrew on a USB stick... that USB stick would be an 'unauthorized device'